# CentraSite Community edition 9.9 - Menu Administration -> Types is disabled

Tags: webmethods

I'm just playing with Centra site community edition and I want to update existing asset types or create my own. 
However Administration -> Types option is disabled. I'm using default Internal\Administration account. 
I have even tried to create new user with Asset Types administration role but it not works either. 
What could be the problem? 
I've tried to search everywhere and have not found any answer.

Thank you

Martin

Build Date: 
2015-08-07 02:10 PM 
Build Number: 
471 
Version: 
9.9.0.0 
Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've find it myself :-) Asset types are not available for community edition.